Functions work on debug mode but not in the release mode Flutter
I am facing a problem here with the Onboarding screen which it is working on the debug mode but when I build my app it doesn't show and pass directly to the Authentication Screen .
I will provide my main.dart file  :
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  AppRouter appRouter = AppRouter();
  String selectedLanguage = 'fr';
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? savedLanguage = prefs.getString('selectedLanguage');
  if (savedLanguage != null) {
    selectedLanguage = savedLanguage;
  }

  runApp(MainApp(
    appRouter: appRouter,
    selectedLanguage: selectedLanguage,
  ));
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String selectedLanguage;
  final AppRouter appRouter;
  const MainApp(
      {super.key, required this.appRouter, required this.selectedLanguage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => UserBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => NavigationBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => CategoryBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => DateBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              TransactionsBloc(dateBloc: BlocProvider.of<DateBloc>(context)),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => StatisticsBloc(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        locale: Locale(selectedLanguage),
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          S.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        ),
        darkTheme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: darkColorScheme,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        ),
        home: const SplashScreen(),
        
        onGenerateRoute: appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}


and I will provide the Splash Screen that shows up first :
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
      SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final int? onBoardingCompleted = _prefs.getInt('onboardingCompleted');

      if (onBoardingCompleted != null && onBoardingCompleted == 1) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/auth');
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/on_boarding');
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/logo.png',
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 30),
        Text(
          "My MIB",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 28,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            color: context.colorScheme.primary,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 100),
        SpinKitFadingCircle(
          color: context.colorScheme.primary,
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}


I thought maybe it is something has to deal with Android manifest and I added the Internet permission because it was the only thing that was in the debug Android manifest and  not in the  main Android Manifest .
I also noticed that in my app if I erased the data from the settings and the relaunch it again , it works perfectly and as it should work .
